# How to convert web font character code to java unicode character?

Tags: java, css, javafx

In JavaFX ican use web fonts like FontAwesomeFX by its uncode value '\uf095' now i want to convert the web font [medical-icons](http://samcome.github.io/webfont-medical-icons/) characters '"\e625"' to java uncode character

Comment: Please could you show us the code you have used to try and rectify your problem?

Comment: Very few of that font's glyphs have Unicode equivalents.  What is the name of the glyph at e625?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `\ue625` already _is_ a Java Unicode character.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the font must either be recreated or be reworked with a font editor. So you have 2 options.
Without and with Font Editor.
With font editor is the easiest and fastest. There can be moved to another position a glyph easily. Icons should always be in the [private use areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) sector. This is also the proffesional away. On the Mac I use as [Glyphs app](https://glyphsapp.com/).

Without font editor need one the icons as a vector file and created with these the font file new. Are helpful webapps like [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/) or pictos.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem solved by add u [image]character after the \ character like '\ue625'